# Using RabbitMQ over HTTP

Tags: http, rabbitmq, amqp

I have to connect an old but critical software to RabbitMQ. The software doesn't support AMQP, but it can do HTTP Requests.

Does RabbitMQ support plain HTTP? Or should I use a "proxy" or "app" that actively transforms the HTTP Requests to AMQP 1.0 and pushes it to the RabbitMQ server?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

> The management plugin supports a simple HTTP API to send and receive messages. This is primarily intended for diagnostic purposes but can be used for low volume messaging without reliable delivery.

As mentioned, it's designed for very low loads, but it may be usable. If you need higher loads, then by all means cast around for a library that does the job and create a proxy. Most languages will have something. I've personally created a lightweight API using Lumen and https://github.com/bschmitt/laravel-amqp to tie a few disparate services together in the past, and it seems to work very well.

Comment: It's high volume, since the old software handles many events. I think the HTTP "bridge" will have to be coded beforehand so the old software can work with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Yeah, if it's high volume, I imagine a little bespoke app would be about right to talk between the two. Without knowing the languages involved, or skills available to you I can't really be more specific, but I knocked together something that linked our devops dashboard with a legacy system running RabbitMQ in under a day, so it's not a massive undertaking (although it was only three different message types in this case).

Comment: Multiple languages. I won't know what else somebody could hook into.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible not but really recommended depending on load. You have three options really, two of which are web socket based and one that seems like what you're looking for. I'd suggest starting with the [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html#http-and-websockets) docs.